# Failed to build WxWidgets with GCC in command prompt

Tags: c++, makefile, wxwidgets, configure

I am following the [official instructions](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.1/docs/msw/install.txt#L239) to build WxWidgets with GCC.  For some reason, it fails to build and gives me this error:

[image: failed]

Could someone tell me what is the problem here?  I did try to use Cygwin to build, but encountered error when trying this line:

```
../configure --enable-debug
```

It complained:

```
-bash: ../configure: No such file or directory
```

I am at the end of my wits now, and cannot figure out how to get it done.  Someone please help.

This is what PATH shows up in commmand prompt:

[image: PATH]

===========================================

OK, I tried something new.

- Using Cygwin64 terminal:

  - `cd /cygdrive/C/wxWidgets-3.1.1/build-debug`
  - `../configure --enable-debug`
  - `make`

Afterwards, I tried:

- `cd samples/minimal`
- `make`

And I encountered this error:

```
g++ -o minimal.exe minimal_sample_rc.o minimal_minimal.o    -L/cygdrive/C/wxWidgets-3.1.1/build-debug/lib -mwindows    -lwx_mswu_core-3.1  -lwx_baseu-3.1    -lwxtiff-3.1 -lwxjpeg-3.1 -lwxpng-3.1   -lwxzlib-3.1 -lwxregexu-3.1 -lwxexpat-3.1 -lrpcrt4 -loleaut32 -lole32 -luuid -luxtheme -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lshlwapi -lcomctl32 -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lversion -lwsock32 -lgdi32 -loleacc -lkernel32 -luser32  -lrpcrt4 -loleaut32 -lole32 -luuid -luxtheme -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lshlwapi -lcomctl32 -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lversion -lwsock32 -lgdi32 -loleacc -lkernel32 -luser32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_mswu_core-3.1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lwx_baseu-3.1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lwxtiff-3.1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lwxjpeg-3.1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lwxpng-3.1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lwxzlib-3.1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lwxregexu-3.1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lwxexpat-3.1
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:149: minimal.exe] Error 1
```

Can someone tell me why my Cygwin64 build failed?

Comment: where did you get the compiler from? What version? Where it is installed? Did you update the $PATH variable so that the toolchain can be found?

Comment: I have Cygwin64 installed.   MinGW64 is installed in hope of fixing the problem.  `gcc -v` gives me GCC posix 7.3.0.

Comment: In the same command line window, type `PATH` and press `enter`. It must show something related to `mingw\bin`, If not, that path must be added.

Comment: In the command prompt windows, `PATH` does show `C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin`.  Is it good?

Comment: Then edit your Windows PATH var or execute `PATH=%PATH%;C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin` before `mingw32-make`

Comment: So add `PATH=%PATH%;` before the link to `....\mingw64\bin` ?

Comment: Add the link by editing Windows environment var called PATH. This is permanent. Executing `PATH=%PATH%;C:\mingw....` only lives while the command line window is opened.

Comment: OK, so my edit to PATH is permanent and it is just fine right?  Can you explain to you why I need `PATH=%PATH%;`?

Comment: OK that doesnt help.  Same error as in picture.

Comment: You only need `PATH=%PATH%;...` as a local update, so Windows can find `mingw32-exe`

Comment: I removed the permanent fix, and only did that temporary fix.  It doesnt work.

Comment: Your PATH may be mixing things. Post it here (edit your question).

Comment: This is `PATH: C:\cygwin64;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin` in Environment Variables.  The result of `PATH` in command prompt is seen in my edited post.

Comment: Remove from that PATH anything related to Python36, cygwin, and mingw. Then restart your computer. It seems they are messing `mingw32-make` (which calls other executables during the proccess). Try the "local" approach.

Comment: This exact problem seems to be addressed by [the documentation](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW)

Answer (score 1):

You have several simple ways to try:

- Use VS 2014 which `PATH` suggests you have installed, and open
  `c:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\build\msw\wx_vc14.sln`;

OR

- Open a console and do

  - `PATH=C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin;%PATH%`
  - `cd c:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\build\msw`
  - `mingw32-make.exe -f makefile.gcc`

OR

Where exactly did you run configure from? You need to be in a *new subfolder* below `c:\wxWidgets-3.1.1`. From that subfolder you run `../configure`, see `c:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\configure` file.

Comment: mingw-w64 comes with batch files to set up the path

Comment: Adding `%PATH% at the end is better than my proposal (at the beginning). It will find executables at the first try, without seeking into the rest of PATH.

Comment: As per [official instructions](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.1/docs/msw/install.txt#L201) I ran `../configure` when I was in `C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\build\msw\build-debug`.  I am doing it right?

Comment: @CaTx: No, you misread them. `$WXWIN`is the location where you had installed wxWidgets, in your case `C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1`. So you need to call `../configure` from `C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\build-debug`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to get it compiled using Command Prompt (console) and this [Wiki guide](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW):

- Open a console:

  - `PATH=C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin;C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\include\wx;%PATH%`
  - `cd c:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\build\msw`
  - `mingw32-make SHELL=CMD.exe -j4 -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release UNICODE=1 SHARED=0`

That extra `SHELL=CMD.exe` saves me from running into some error codes.  I still have problem with the Cygwin64 method.  Will update.