# Error message when building WxWidgets sample program

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, wxwidgets

I was trying to follow the instructions [here](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_and_getting_started) to setup WxWidgets.

I've managed to run the commands `wx-config --version` and `wx-config --list` but not the commands to compile the minimal example, which are:

cd gtk-build/samples/minimal
make
./minimal

After lots of display messages I arrive at:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwxtiff-3.1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwxjpeg-3.1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwxregexu-3.1
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [minimal] Error 1
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'minimal' failed
The command '/bin/sh -c make' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Did I miss the installation of some library?

There is a similar [question for windows here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50953431/failed-to-build-wxwidgets-with-gcc-in-command-prompt), but the answers there seem not to apply for linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please look at the [official instructions](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/plat_gtk_install.html) rather than the wiki which may, or not, be up to date.

Second, by running `make clean` you removed the libraries used by the in-tree makefiles. So, unsurprisingly, you can't use them any more, but you can use `makefile.unx` from the source tree, i.e. if `wx-config` is in your `PATH`, just use `make -f makefile.unx` in `$wx/samples/minimal` (and *not* under `gtk-build/samples/minimal`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using the wiki. As the reference I was following said, I did go to the gtk-build directory and ran `make`, then `make install` and `make clean`. Then, after cd-ing to /gtk-build/smaples/minimal I've tried running `make` and got this error.

Comment: I've preferred to remove the `make clean` command, cd to `/gtk-build/samples/minimal`, call make. Apparently works, thanks a lot =)